# Ruby Regex to Match Both Unix And Windows File Paths

Tags: ruby, regex, filepath

The following instance method takes a file path and returns the file's prefix (the part before the separator):

```rb
@separator = "@"

def table_name path
  regex = Regexp.new("\/[^\/]+#{@separator}")
  path.match(regex)[0].gsub(/^.|.$/,'').downcase.to_sym
end

table_name "bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv"
# => :prefix
```

So far, this method only works on Unix. To make it work on Windows, I also need to capture the backslash (\). Unfortunately, that's when I got stuck:

```rb
@separator = "@"

def table_name path
  regex = Regexp.new("(\/|\\)[^\/\\]+#{@separator}")
  path.match(regex)[0].gsub(/^.|.$/,'').downcase.to_sym
end

table_name("bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv")
# RegexpError: premature end of char-class: /(\/|\)[^\/\]+@/

# Target result:
table_name("bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv")
# => :prefix
table_name("bla\bla\bla\Prefix@invoice.csv")
# => :prefix
```

I suspect Ruby's string interpolation and escaping is what confuses me here.

How could I change the Regex to make it work on both Unix and Windows?

Comment: I thought there was a Ruby constant that handled this - it'd be `/` in Unix and `\` in Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't actually know what `bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv` refers to; is `bla/bla/bla/bla` all directories, and the filename `Prefix@invoice.csv`?

With the assumption that I've correctly understood your filenames, I suggest using `File.split()`:

```
irb> (path, name) = File.split("bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv")
=> ["bla/bla/bla", "Prefix@invoice.csv"]
irb> (prefix, postfix) = name.split("@")
=> ["Prefix", "invoice.csv"]
```

Not only is it platform-agnostic, it is more legible too.

**Update**

You piqued my curiosity:

```
>> wpath="blah\\blah\\blah\\Prefix@invoice.csv"
=> "blah\\blah\\blah\\Prefix@invoice.csv"
>> upath="bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv"
=> "bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv"
>> r=Regexp.new(".+[\\\\/]([^@]+)@(.+)")
=> /.+[\\\/]([^@]+)@(.+)/
>> wpath.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "blah\\blah\\blah\\Prefix@invoice.csv" 1:"Prefix" 2:"invoice.csv">
>> upath.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "bla/bla/bla/Prefix@invoice.csv" 1:"Prefix" 2:"invoice.csv">
```

You're right, the `\` must be double-escaped for it to work in a regular expression: once to get past the interpreter, again to get past the regex engine. (Definitely feels awkward.) The regex is:

```
.+[\\/]([^@]+)@(.+)
```

The string is:

```
".+[\\\\/]([^@]+)@(.+)"
```

The regex, which might be too brittle for real use (how would it handle a path without `/` or `\` path separators or a pathname without `@` or with too many `@`?), looks for any number of characters, a single path separator, any amount of non-@, an @, then any amount of any characters. I'm assuming that the first `.+` will greedily consume as many characters as possible to make the match as far to the *right* as possible:

```
>> evil_path="/foo/bar@baz/blorp/Prefix@invoice.csv"
=> "/foo/bar@baz/blorp/Prefix@invoice.csv"
>> evil_path.match(r)
=> #<MatchData "/foo/bar@baz/blorp/Prefix@invoice.csv" 1:"Prefix" 2:"invoice.csv">
```

But depending upon malformed input data, it might do the very wrong thing.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution!  
As I am not familiar enough with Ruby's class libraries yet, all I could think of was using regex. However, I still wonder how I might make my approach work. I read about double escaping in Ruby, but I am not sure if that applies here.

Comment: I had to know, so I went and tried it. :) Not too bad, but I don't think it is as immediately legible.

Comment: I am glad you had to know :-) Even if using a regex might not be the best solution here, I learnt a lot about how regular expressions are handled in Ruby by just trying out your code examples. Thank you very much for that!  
On a side note, the following answer also adds some more information: [Backslash and captured group within Ruby regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755505/backslash-captured-group-within-ruby-regular-expression).